# spring-security: create session without HTTP request?

Tags: java, session, spring-security

Is it possible within the Spring Security framework to create a session without an associated HTTP request? I'm developing an application that deploys on Tomcat, but users access it via a persistent SIP connection. Up until now I've written my own session management code but would like to know if I could delegate it to Spring Security.

Apache Shiro has 'heterogeneous client access' for its session implementation, allowing any type of client to access and manipulate sessions like what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you want is possible. However I'm not sure how easy it will be.

Keep in mind I don't have any experience with SIP in Java. But I have extended Spring Security on a number of occasions. You'll need to take the following general steps to get it working:

- Define and configure your own security chain ([see the Security Filter Chain reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html)).
- Create a custom [SecurityContextRepository](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextRepository.html) and link it to the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.
- You probably won't be able to use a number of filters because they require a HttpServletRequest (SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter, RememberMeAuthenticationFilter) so you might need to implement your own.